# Внутри while создание 2 мерного массива и его наполнение

Tags: php, mysql, while

На стареньком php пытаюсь запустить такой скрипт:

```
while ($event_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_db_answer)){
$puth_query_data_answer = mysql_query(
    "
Запрос возвращает массив с ключом 'puth'.
    "
);
    while ($puth_query_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($puth_query_data_answer)){
        $event_data['event_name'][] = $puth_query_data['puth'];
    }
}
```

Не создаётся двумерный массив `$event_data['event_name'][]`.

При этом вот такое работает:

```
$event_db_answer = mysql_query(" возвращает массив с ключем - 'event_name'");
while ($event_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_db_answer)){

    if($event_data['event_name'] != ''){
        if($same_event != $event_data['event_name']){
            $same_event = $event_data['event_name'];
        }
        if($same_event == $event_data['event_name']){
            $event_arr["$same_event"][] = substr($event_data['puth'], 14);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите что не так?

Comment: Извините, конечно, но зачем старенький? В новеньком (>=5.3) вместо стандартного api mysql (которое официально устарело и больше не обслуживается) есть PDO. Там fetch операции возвращают очень удобные массивы. Сам долго ломался, но у него возможностей намного больше, и многие мои проблемы решились.

Comment: `$event_data` каждый раз перезаписывается новым значением от `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: То что MySQL функции mysql_* - must die, это верно, но мир не закончился на одном PDO, и можно использовать аналогичные старым MySQL-функциям функции mysql**i**_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказал u_mulder, $event_data при каждой итерации цикла обновляется. Во втором варианте $event_arr у вас ничем не перекрывается. Для первого варианта создайте отдельный массив, в который будет записываться результат:

```
$event_data_names = array();
while ($event_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_db_answer)){

    $puth_query_data_answer = mysql_query("Запрос возвращает массив с ключом 'puth'.");

    while ($puth_query_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($puth_query_data_answer)){
       $event_data_names[] = $puth_query_data['puth'];
    }

}
```